# I want to track the phone number of who is accessing the website via ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to track the phone number of the user, accessing the website.

Comment: Not possible. Apple will never allow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phone number is not returned by Mobile Safari.  It would be considered a privacy violation.

Unless he/she entered their phone number *voluntarily* into some text field that's used by a cookie only for your website.